# Plotting with a for loop in matplotlib, skipping indices

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I have a csv file containing columns of data arranged as such: x,y,err,x,y,err,x,y,err etc. I need to plot on the same window each (x,y) pair of columns with the associated errorbars. I want to use a for loop to do this, I was thinking for a very basic start something like this:

```
a=np.genfromtxt('datafile')
for i in range(60):
    ax.errorbar(a[:,i], a[:,i+1], yerr= a[:,i+2])
```

Am I on the right track?

But I also need 'i' to only take one out every three values, aka I need 'i' to cycle through the values 0,2,5,8... to make sure each i corresponds to an 'x' column, each i+1 to a 'y' column and each i+2 to a error column. How can I do that? Sorry if it is pretty basic, I am fairly new to Python and can use any help! Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation, when it is available, is your best friend.

To get `i` to increment steps of 3, see the `step` argument in the  [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) of `range()`:

> `range(start,stop[, step])`
>
> ...
>   If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 * step, ...].

Other than that, it looks fine.